# How to copy charaters from string pointer to string vector?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector

I have a array of characters and `packet` is a pointer to this array. I want to copy middle part of this array to a vector of strings:

```
void TCP::new_packet(flow_info key, const u_char* packet, time_t timer){
    std::vector(std::string);   
    //I want to add bytes 3 to 7 of the packet to the vector!
}
```

Who I can do it?

Comment: Have you bothered to look at the methods available in `std::string`?

Comment: The elements of a string are characters, not strings.

Comment: @molbdnilo So what shall I do?

Comment: @Abraham -- Why are you introducing pointers, when [substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) can do this work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is simplified version of another problem. I have a function that one of its arguments are a pointer to u_char array. I want to store middle of this array in a vector.

Comment: @Abraham You didn't do your research in the various ways to construct a `std::string`.  [Please look at constructor 4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).  Your question boils down to "how do I construct a std::string given a char* pointer and a size?".

Answer (score 3):

> I want to copy middle part of this array to a vector of strings:

If the goal is to copy a portion of a char array to a `std::string`, use the [std::string constructor (4)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a pointer to a char and a size:

```
void TCP::new_packet(flow_info key, const u_char* packet, time_t timer)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    // I want to add bytes 3 to 7 of the packet to the vector
    v.push_back(std::string(packet+3, 5));
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Sw5NwG)

---

Edit:

Since you're using `u_char`, you can create a simple function to do the work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

void addToVector(const u_char* data, std::vector<std::string>& v, 
                 int start, int end)
{
    v.push_back(std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data) + start, 
                end - start + 1));
}

int main() 
{
    const u_char p[] = "abc123456";
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    addToVector(p, v, 3, 7);
    std::cout << v[0];
}
```

[Live Example 2](http://ideone.com/5sQ0Iu)

Comment: Works fine with `char *`. But returns error for `u_char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
 std::string str = "This is a test!";
 strings.push_back(str.substr(3, 4));
```

And what is this??:

```
u_char *middle;
middle = &str;
```

Comment: What if I had  `u_char uc = "This is a test!";` instead of string?

Comment: You can't put a string in a char... And why would you do that? You don't want to use substr?

Comment: Question Updated.

Comment: are you forced tu use an unsigned char instead of a char?

Comment: Second parameter to `substr` is the size, not the ending index.

Comment: Edited, but it isn't what he's asking for anymore :/

Comment: But still, you didn't edited correctly, it should be `substr(3, 5)` instead of `4`. And it doesn't matter whether he asked for it or not, but whatever you answer, at-least answer it right.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer too instead of saying "you're wrong"

Answer (score 0):

You can base what you want to do with the following piece of code using`std::copy_n`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

```
const std::string str { "123456789" };
std::vector<char> sub;
auto iter = std::begin(str);
// use advance to make this clear when you read.
std::advance(iter, 3);
// from where the advance left the iterator, and go fw 4 positions.
std::copy_n(iter, 4, std::back_inserter(sub));
for (auto c: sub) {
    std::cout << c << "\n";
}
```

[Try it!](http://ideone.com/kxNJCn)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you need the variable of middle, 
but if you want to copy a slice of string to a 
"vector(string)" ,then firstly you need to construct a new string to hold the slice of original string str.code like that:

```
string temp;    
for(int i=3;i<8;i++)
{
    temp.push_back(str[i]);
}
strings.push_back(temp);
```

Comment: re-read your code

Comment: what is it?@Treycos

Comment: you're using push_back on a string.... and by a "str" which is... idk